# Cayleys Theorem worked example

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Find the smallest n such that $S_4 \times S_8$ is isomorphic to a subgroup in $S_n$.

**Answer**

By Lagrange, we know that the minimum $n$ has to be at least $12$. But also if $n=12$ then this is easy to find a subgroup of $S_{12}$ by permuting first 4 numbers juxtaposed with permuting last 8 numbers.

Comment: Compute the order of $S_{11}$, you will see that $S_4\times S_8$ is not isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{11}$.

Comment: @HongyiHuang I know that the order of $S_{11}$ = $11!$ but I am not too sure how to further that

Comment: $(8!\times 4!)\nmid 11!$.